# Can't access internet from Ubuntu installed inside virtual machine behind corporate proxy

Tags: networking, internet, proxy

Host OS - Window 7 professional

Installed Ubuntu 16.04 inside Virtual Machine (VMWare)

While internet is freely accessible in the host OS I can't access it inside the virtual machine.

The curious thing is my company has provided a pre-configured CentOS image which inside the virtual machine can access internet.

The VMWare settings for both CentOS and Ubuntu are same. Also the network settings inside both the OS have been checked to be the same.

What can be the solution for this?

Result of ifconfig

```
$ ifconfig
ens33     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:33:ff:fb  
      inet addr:192.168.11.135  Bcast:192.168.11.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::b06b:940a:7007:4783/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:7218 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:7391 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:1018925 (1.0 MB)  TX bytes:642150 (642.1 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:14746 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:14746 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:1448722 (1.4 MB)  TX bytes:1448722 (1.4 MB)
```

Result of sudo ufw status

```
Status: inactive
```

Result of env | grep -i proxy

```
$ env | grep -i proxy
http_proxy=http://{my.company.proxy}:8080
HTTPS_PROXY=http://{my.company.proxy}:8080
https_proxy=http://{my.company.proxy}:8080
HTTP_PROXY=http://{my.company.proxy}:8080
```

I have hidden my actual company proxy.

Result of more /etc/apt/apt.conf

```
more: stat of /etc/apt/apt.conf failed: No such file or directory
```

proxy is not installed. I can't install it as there is no internet connection.

Comment: Time to start troubleshooting then.  Please post the output of `ifconfig` and `sudo ufw status`.

Comment: Edit you answer and add the output of these `env | grep -i proxy`; `more /etc/apt/apt.conf` and proxy ip and proxy port.

Comment: @rclocher3 - I have edited the question details with the said edits